# In memory Cache for Java that does not use JVM Heap space

Tags: java, caching, in-memory

I am looking for In memory Cache for Java that does not use JVM Heap space.

I have looked into EhCache and JCS but both of them uses the Heap.

I want it to be scalable.

Comment: I would use Java Chronicle for this (as I wrote it) but it depends on what your caching requirements are. It may be simple enough to write your own.  What are your exact requirements?  A feature I have in Java Chronicle is the ability to serialize objects or use data off heap with very little garbage produced (or none)  BTW It is persisted as well almost for free. ;)

Comment: Are you looking for something free? What about a JavaSpaces implementation such as GigaSpaces? This caches across VMs for scalability. The only question is, is it a hammer to crack a nut?

Comment: I need a key - value mapping cache just like the one in ehcache, but it should not use jvm heap space. I want it to be scale able. heap space is limited for me.

Comment: You can also consider Oracle Coherence http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/coherence/overview/index.html. You can choose diffrent JVM for maintaining the cache by simple config changes.

Comment: I am looking for an open solution

Comment: Sorry I didnt get that question in the suggestions. I am not able to delete the post as there is an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also consider to use  [HazelCast In Memory Data Grid](http://www.hazelcast.com/) solution. I have used it, I would say its one of the best solution I came across.